# extract a word colon space few words

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, stringr

I need to extract two patterns from the text field One is "From: alpha beta" and other is "To: gemma delta" from the following dataframe.

```
df <- tibble(text=c("From: alpha beta", "To: gemma delta"))
```

I am using this..

```
from_pattern <- regex("[From]:\\s[alpha beta]")
to_pattern <- regex("[To]:\\s[gemma delta]")

df <- df%>% 
  mutate(to = if_else(str_detect(text, to_pattern), "to", NA_character_),
         from = if_else(str_detect(text, from_pattern), "from", NA_character_))
```

but I am not getting the desired result. What am I missing here? It would be great if I get the output in one column like the following:

df <- tibble(text=c("From: alpha beta", "To: gemma delta"),
             tofrom = c("from", "to"))

Comment: You say you need to extract "From: alpha beta", although it's not in your search string ("From: gemma delta" is)...

Comment: Just updated the text. Sorry about the typos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you want to know if a string starts with `From:` or `To:`:

```
df %>% mutate(tofrom = tolower(str_extract(text, '(?i)^(from|to)(?=: .*)')))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  text              tofrom
#  <chr>             <chr> 
#1 From: gemma delta from  
#2 To: alpha beta    to
```

Here use `(?i)` modifier to ignore case to make the match more generic, and then match the word `from` or `to` from the start of the string followed by `:`.

If you need to match the pattern exactly:

```
df %>% mutate(tofrom = tolower(str_extract(text, '(?i)^(from(?=: gemma delta$)|to(?=: alpha beta$))')))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  text              tofrom
#  <chr>             <chr> 
#1 From: gemma delta from  
#2 To: alpha beta    to
```

Comment: I need to check alpha beta and gemma delta in front of "From: " and "To: " as well in the text and use str_detect to then create tofrom with "from" and "to" values. Can you help again?

Comment: From can be generic, but I need to check gemma delta in front of "To: " in the text and then create tofrom with "from" and "to" values.

Comment: See the update. Simply replace `.*` with the pattern you want to match exactly.

Comment: What's the role of ?= in regex?

Comment: It stands for [look ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which means matches `from` or `to` followed by another pattern. They are necessary here because look around are zero length assertions, i.e. they assert a pattern is followed by another but don't consume characters, so the patterns after `?=` are discarded in the result.